# PhpMailer SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I got an issue with phpMailer, i can't send any e-mail, and it gives me this error:

```
2016-03-03 21:32:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 2016-03-03 21:32:09 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected 2016-03-03 21:32:09 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2016-03-03 21:32:09 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Erreur : SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

This is my code :

```
<?php require('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); 
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth= true;
$mail->Username='myadress@gmail.com';
$mail->Password='passwordgmail';
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SetFrom('myadress@gmail.com', 'Name');
$mail->AddAddress('someone@gmail.com', 'HisName');
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail    clients";
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Error : ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Ok!!';
  } 
?>
```

I tried all the answers i found, but none of them worked so far. I also tried other ports, the 25 and 465 don't work and give me other errors. If someone could help me please it would be really nice =) . Thank you

Answer (score 36):

You're using `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` with `Port = 587`. That won't work. Use `ssl` / 465 or `tls`/ 587; don't mix them up. This (and many other problems) are covered in the troubleshooting guide the error message links to.

Also note that the `ssl:` prefix in your `Host` value will override the value in `SMTPSecure`, so I'd suggest you remove it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer =) . So i tried ssl/465 and tls/587 , and none of them worked. with ssl/465 i got this :
    "SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again  SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2016-03-04 08:32:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2016-03-04 08:32:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection x186sm2143474wmg.19 - gsmtp 2016-03-04 08:32:12 SMTP connect() failed .   "


Do I need to change the php.ini file?

Comment: Ok so i decided to set to false the SMTPAuth . Now I got this :  SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed . SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected.  SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: xxxx.

I have no idea why the recipients failed..

Comment: So you're surprised it doesn't work when you turn off authentication for a service that requires it? I'd also advise you not to run with scissors. Just read the error message, read the docs; it's all there.

Comment: Ok thanks, It works, i change the smtp to my IAP  , turned on the auth, and i put an adress@myIAP and the right password.  Thank you again =)

Answer (score 5):

```
require('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php'); 
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(true);
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // not ssl://smtp.gmail.com
$mail->SMTPAuth= true;
$mail->Username='myadress@gmail.com';
$mail->Password='passwordgmail';
$mail->Port = 465; // not 587 for ssl 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SetFrom('myadress@gmail.com', 'Name');
$mail->AddAddress('someone@gmail.com', 'HisName');
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail    clients";
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo 'Error : ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Ok!!';
}
```

https://www.google.com/settings/u/0/security/lesssecureapps enable this